# Incorrect column name after loading csv

Tags: r

After loading csv, the name of the first column changed from "communityname" to "Êcommunityname".

```
crime=read.csv('crimedata.csv',check.names=FALSE)
```

Any one knows why and how to solve it?

Comment: check the csv file in notepad or any other text editor. Or open the csv file in excel and save it in csv format. Sometime file with csv file is saved in other format like unicode.

Comment: try to use this specific fileEncoding = "UTF-8"

Comment: Your file seems to be containing unicode characters, you can try fixing that by using: 
`names(crime) <- gsub('\\W+','',names(crime), perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks for all your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct your Encoding. Try to use `fileEncoding` to correct it!